# How to import data into Excel from SSAS Tabular model as Table?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, ssas, excel-2013, tabular

I'm trying to import data from SSAS Tabular Model into Excel worksheet.
Steps sequence:

1. On the `Data` tab -> From Other Sources -> From Analysis Services
2. Select Database and Model
3. Save Data Connection -> Finish

And then appeared the popup window (see below) where I can choose `how I want to view this data` and there `Table` option is inactive (see below).

Maybe someone know why it's inactive and how I can get my data imported as a simple table?

[image]

And yes... I personally NEVER saw this `Table` option as active.

Comment: Unfortunately You can't.  SSAS is designed for Read-Only consumption.  Therefore a Table option would be counter intuitive.  What they can do is take the resulting PivotTable, Copy/Paste, and do what they want with that information.  It will not effect the Cube or anything, just the data will be Point in Time set of information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to start a PivotTable connected to SSAS Tabular, drop a measure into the PivotTable, then double click the cell with the measure value in order to drillthrough. It brings up a QueryTable with the drillthrough results. At that point, you can right click on the QueryTable and edit the query. Set the query to:

```
 EVALUATE('Your Table')
```

At this point you can delete the PivotTable if you wish.

Another approach involving editing an ODC file is [posted](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2009/12/18/binding-an-excel-table-to-the-results-of-an-mdx-query/) by Chris Webb but my suggestion from above is mentioned at the end of that post. Also Marco Russo has a [writeup](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/import-data-from-tabular-model-in-excel-using-a-dax-query/) of this ODC approach.

Comment: Excellent! Very useful. Thank you!